# What is the difference between 'locate' and 'find' in Linux?

Tags: linux

Why there are two so similar command in Linux? and normally what are the circumstances to use each of them?

Comment: For better answers in both depth and completeness, see [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60205/locate-vs-find-usage-pros-and-cons-of-each-other) at [unix.se].

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`find` searches in the real system. Is slower but always up-to-date and has more options (size, modification time,...)

`locate` uses a previously built database (command `updatedb`). Is much faster, but uses an 'older' database and searches only names or parts of them.

In any case, `man find` and `man locate` will help you further.

Comment: ...and `updatedb` do roughly someting like `find / -type f | gzip > locate.gz`.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60205/locate-vs-find-usage-pros-and-cons-of-each-other answers this question in more detail.

Answer (score 5):

Both the `locate` and `find` commands will find a file, but they work in quite different ways.

`locate` will work in an offline mode:

- For a simple explanation, the file indexing database in Unix system called *slocate* will list the locations of all files which ship with the Unix system. When you execute `locate`, it'll use that database to search for a particular file.  The problem with `locate` is if you just created a file which you now want to search for, *locate* will not work because the *slocate* database is not up-to-date.  To overcome this problem, you can use `updatedb` to update the *slocate* database. Executing `locate` again will now find the newly created file.  Thus, many Linux system administrators use a `cron` job to regularly update the *slocate* database.

`find` will work in an online/"in real time" mode.

- It will actually go and search all the directories to find the particular file specified and it examine each file one-by-one. Therefore, it requires a lot of I/O calls.

So based on the nature, it is clear that locate is faster than find but find is real time.

Hope this will help to clear the idea. All the best. :)

Answer (score 2):

`locate` simply looks its database and reports the file location.

`find` does not use a database, it traverses all the directories and their sub directories and looks for files matching the given criterion.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, the 'locate' command searches in a .db file called mlocate.db, that file contains all your filesystem files path. It is up-to-date once a day I think by a corn job, so it's much faster than 'find' command because 'find' search in the directory given as parameter and all the subdirectories, that means using a lot of I/O calls.

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using find is the locate command. This command is often quicker and can search the entire file system with ease.
You can install the command with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mlocate
```

The reason locate is faster than find is because it relies on a database of the files on the filesystem.
The database is usually updated once a day with a cron script, but you can update it manually by typing:

```
sudo updatedb
```

Run this command now. Remember, the database must always be up-to-date if you want to find recently acquired or created files.