# Difference between locate and which in Linux

Tags: linux, locate, which

What is the difference between `locate` and `which` in Linux?

Why when I use `locate mentor` does it list all the mentor but when I used `which mentor` it says "no mentor in..." - what does this mean?

Comment: See this related http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60208/84427

Comment: There are also `where` and [`whereis`](http://superuser.com/questions/40301/which-whereis-differences).

Comment: in bash, prefer : `type -all acommand` . And If I read the XYProblem behind your question : you have a command, you can see it via locate, but can't execute it ? then edit PATH, either in your specific user's `~/.profile` file, or if you are convinced you know what to do, in the global `/etc/profile` file [WARNING: you may break system scripts (and possibly a lot of the OS) if you add the wrong path in the $PATH of /etc/profile... (ex: paths containing commands usually found elswhere). Prefer only adding at the END of the variable. And please do not put `::` or a `.`  anywhere in that PATH.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between 'locate' and 'find' in Linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/199472/what-is-the-difference-between-locate-and-find-in-linux)

Answer (score 45):

#### What is the difference between `locate` and `which`?

`locate` uses a previously built database to locate the file.

> `locate` reads one or more databases prepared by `updatedb`(8) and writes file names matching at least one of the PATTERNs to standard output, one per line.

Source [locate(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locate)

> `updatedb` creates or updates a database used by `locate`(1). If the
>   database already exists, its data is reused to avoid rereading
>   directories that have not changed.
>
> `updatedb` is usually run daily by `cron`(8) to update the default
>   database (`/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db`)

Source [updatedb(8) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/updatedb)

---

`which` looks for an executable file by searching for it in the directories in the `PATH` environmental variable.

> `which` takes one or more arguments. For each of its arguments it prints to `stdout` the full path of the executables that would have been executed when this argument had been entered at the shell prompt. It does this by searching for an executable or script in the directories listed in the environment variable `PATH`.

using the same algorithm as `bash`(1).

Source [which(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/which)

---

#### `locate mentor` lists mentor, but `which mentor` says "no mentor in..."

> What does that mean?

You have some files named `mentor` which can be found in the `locate` database.

You don't have an executable file or script named `mentor` in your `PATH`.

Comment: "updatedb" - good to know it's not just Microsoft that comes up with overly non-specific names for things. (In Win32, `DeleteObject` deletes a GDI object, `CloseHandle` closes a kernel handle, etc. Similarly `updatedb` updates the `locate` DB)

Comment: "which" is also specifically useful in the event that you may have multiple versions of the same program kicking about in various places in your path, so it tells you which one is actually executed when you run the command. This has been helpful for me before in diagnosing unexpected behaviour - for instance, it helped me realise I had left a manually installed version of a utility on my system such that it was overriding the version installed by the package manager.

Answer (score 12):

`which` is to locate a command (`which` returns a path name of the files / links that would be executed in the current environment)

`locate` is to find files by name (`locate` reads one or more databases prepared by `updatedb` and writes files names matching at least one of the patterns to standered output, one per line)

Comment: Please provide attribution for your sources — the descriptions in your answer are taken directly from the man pages for those utilities.

Answer (score 6):

`locate` takes a glob pattern by default (Regex pattern can be used too) and searches the database `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db` for any filename matching the pattern.

`which` is a command to search for the full path of a command in the directories interpreted by the `PATH` environment variable.